# Why does isPrime using i*i < n return a correct answer for every int except 2^31- 1

Tags: java, int, primes, integer-overflow, modulo

consider this code:

```java
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++)
    if (n % i == 0) return false;
    return n > 1;
}

public static int squareOf(int n) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i * i < n)
    i++;

    return i * i == n ? i: -1;
}
```

since  (46340)*(46340)< Integer.MAX_VALUE < (46341)*(46341), i*i overflows.

what I expect then, is that for numbers bigger than (46340)*(46340), isPrime either does not terminate, or eventually stops but gives some random answer.

what happens is for every single int < Integer.MAX_VALUE, it gives a correct answer !! and for Integer.Max_value it gives a wrong one.

**Why** does this happen?

---

in squareOf, we have i * i < n , instead of i * i <= n:

for the range [(46 340)^2 + 1 , 2147483641]: it is correct, except for: {2147402577, 2147465721, 2147469348,
2147478505, 2147481513, 2147481513, 2147482825, 2147482929, 2147483280, 2147483536, 2147483556, 2147483609, 2147483620, 2147483641}

[2147483642 , Integer.MAX_VALUE]: it seems to not terminate.

**why** does it give a correct answer **for a lot** of values?

**what's special** about the values where it gives a wrong answer?

**why** does it not terminate for values after 2147483641 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems to be the following:

Understood: The last int `n` for which the loop condition `i*i <= n` makes sense is 2147395600. For n=2147395600 the loop terminates when i = 46340. For all ints between [2147395601, 2147483647] inclusive the value `i*i <= n` is true when i reaches 36340, and therefore will proceed on to i=34341 at which point `i*i` overflows and thus is no longer sensible.

Not understood: Why then does the `isPrime` function correctly distinguish primes and composites among the 88047 ints in the interval [2147395601, 2147483647] inclusive, the interval for which the loop termination condition is no longer sensible?

First off, it's important to understand that every composite number in the questionable interval has already been identified before the loop reached i=46340. Thus only for prime values of n will the loop even get that far. Now the remaining question is why does the function almost always correctly identify as prime the 4085 primes in the interval.  And the answer for that is also relatively simple. The result of `i*i` when `i*i` overflows (i.e when `i*i` is mathematically greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) is equivalent to taking the low-order 32 bits of i*i and "stuffing" them into an int. However, the calculation `n%i` never overflows, so the loop will never exit via that condition (because n must be prime). Therefore the loop will only exit because `i*i` is greater than n and correctly return `true`, or it will not exit at all and become an infinite loop.

We now have to show why the loop exits, and what goes wrong in the above analysis for n=`Integer.MAX_VALUE`. What we need for loop to exit is an `i` for which `i*i` overflows in such a way that the low-order 32 bits of the square have bit 32 equal to zero and the remaining 31 bits form an integer greater than n. That's a fairly narrow range. And just by luck there happen to be values of i for which the overflow of `i*i` hits right in that range, allowing the loop to exit. The value i=593968971 will work for all values, you can test this for yourself. There are smaller values for all the primes below 2147483629 in the interval, which you can find by experiment.

`Integer.MAX_VALUE` is an exception to the above statements. The reason is again simple. There are no positive ints greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so the loop can never exit via `i*i > n`. However, when `i` finally hits `Integer.MAX_VALUE` the loop will exit and the function will return false because n%i is equal to n%n which is always 0.

Comment: Thanks,  and 593968971^2 = 2147483641, that's why squareOf doesn't terminate for numbers bigger than 2147483641.

Answer (score 4):

Well, when `n == Integer.MAX_VALUE` the loop doesn't terminate until `i == n`, at which point `n % i` is `0`, and you wrongly return `false`.

The reason `i` gets to iterate till it reaches the value of `n` (when `n==Integer.MAX_VALUE`) is that `i * i` can never be larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so the loop can never terminate unless you break out of it by returning `false`.

Comment: ... because when i > sqrt(n) then i*i < 0 < n, and thus continues looping.

Comment: @JoopEggen well, `i*i` won't always be negative when is overflows (I checked), but it will always be smaller than `n` (when`n` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but my question not  about "what is happening", but why is it happening. how can I edit the question to make it clear?

Comment: @Slei Weren't you asking why you get a wrong result for Integer.MAX_VALUE? That's what I explained in my answer.

Comment: No, I asked why I get a correct result for every number x where:  (46 340)^2 <   x < Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Comment: The fact that it returns a wrong answer for Integer.MAX_VALUE is not surprsing, the fact that it gives a correct answer for primes that are big enough so that i*i overflows is surprising.

Comment: @Slei well, for `n < Integer.MAX_VALUE`, `i * i <= n` may become false even if `i*i` overflows. Can you give an example of a prime number between  (46 340)^2 and Integer.MAX_VALUE? It will be easy enough to check for which value of `i` the loop terminates.

Comment: 2147483629 for example. it's actually for all primes less than Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: @Slei well, I tested this value. When `i` reaches `593968971`, `i*i` (which obviously overflows) results in `2147483641`, which is larger than `2147483629`. Hence the loop terminates before `i` reaches `2147483629`, which is why you get the correct result - true. In other words, you got lucky. That said, you can't rely on the results of overflowing computations.

Comment: The weird thing is we are getting lucky for every single prime (except MAX_VALUE). that's why I asked this question, thinking that there is a mathematical reason behind it.